# Load from .json file, sort data according to value then save it to same .json file

Tags: python, json, sorting

The JSON file I have:

```json
[{
"key_a": "value",
"key_b": [{
        "key_a": "c",
        "key_b": null
    },
    {
        "key_a": "b",
        "key_b": null
    }]
}]
```

The format I want:

```json
[{
    "key_a": "value",
    "key_b": [{
            "key_a": "b",
            "key_b": null
        },
        {
            "key_a": "c",
            "key_b": null
        }]
}]
```

How can I sort child elements according to the value of key (for example according to 'key_a') then save it to the source JSON file from where data was loaded?

What I have in mind is something like this:

```py
def read_json_file():
    with open(filename) as file:
        var = json.load(file)
    file.close()

def sort_json_var():
    ...

def write_json_file():
    with open (filename, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's builtin function `sorted` can do this. If `var` is your loaded json file (you probably want to pass it in to `sort_json_var`), then

```py
sorted(var[0]["key_b"], key=lambda x:x["key_a"])
```

will return the inner part of what you want, as long as every element in it has `key_a`.
Then all that's left is to assign that result back to `var[0]["key_b"]`.

Comment: How do I generate path for the child (e.g. var[0]['child'][1]['child'])? I have the index [] stored in array but I cannot simply add them like string (e.g. var[0]['child'] + [1]['child'])

Comment: @nirajgiriXD I'm not sure what you mean, is it related to the exact same problem you originally posted about? If not, you should start a new question as more people will see it.

Comment: I have values stored in array for the element I want to acess in array (arr). So whenever I need to access the same element, instead of searching again I can directly access using var[arr[0]]['child'][arr[1]]['child']. So thats why I am trying to get a pattern like var[arr[0]]['child'][arr[1]]['child'].